# How should I temporarily remove OSB subfloor in order to re-use the material when I replace it?

Tags: flooring

I need to remove an OSB sub-floor from the floor joists in my walk-in closets in order to gain access to a concrete slab that is below the joists. I will be replacing the subfloor after repairs are made to the slab.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to remove the OSB in such a way as to be able to re-use as much of it as possible to replace the subfloor after the concrete slab repairs are complete.

The 14 year-old OSB seems to be in good shape with no signs of water damage, so I'd hate to buy new material if any of it can be re-used. I suspect that OSB will tend to break up when I try to free it from the joists. It's surface nailed down and I suspect there is glue or construction adhesive as well. Some of the boards run underneath finished walls, so I know I'll have to cut those somehow.

How can I remove the OSB in order to re-use as much as possible? To ask a similar question from another direction, is there any point to replacing it with new material?

Thanks!

EDIT: user isherwood raised an important point that made me realize I don't really need to pull it all up, I just need to remove enough between the joists so that I can get to the slab. So my solution will be to do just that: cut access with a saw and then nail the OSB back in place to floating backing lumber.

I'm going to mark the one answer provided as accepted since it does answer my question about is it possible and why or why not.

Comment: Adhesive and working from on top makes it quite difficult to remove in decent pieces for reuse.  If it was just nails/screws it would be possible to carefully remove the nails first.

Comment: If just needing to remove flooring from between two joists, could cut at edge of joists and remove that section.  Add(sister) wood to joists after to have place for nailing back.

Comment: Are you removing it for repair clearance or just for bodily access? How large of areas?

Comment: You could try undoing every screw or punching down every nail, but any amount of adhesive is going to make it impossible to reuse the old osb. Sorry.

Comment: @isherwood Removing it for body/tool access.

Comment: Then you don't need to remove it from the joists. You can cut an access opening and patch that back in with floated lumber backing. "Remove the subfloor" is somewhat of an overstatement.

Comment: @isherwood I see your point. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reasonable chance would be to drill around every nailhead with a hollow drill, and hope the construction adhesive, if present, isn't doing a lot.

The point to replacing it with new material is pretty much one of if the construction adhesive is doing much, you're going to have damage when you remove the sheet, so you'll want an undamaged sheet to replace it.

Comment: There are nail pullers with hollow punches made to remove material around the nail head so you can get at it [like this one](https://www.amazon.com/Dewalt-DWHT55524-10-Claw-Bar/dp/B00GO45DK8).

Comment: I agree, but a simple "cat's paw" nail puller will do. If necessary the divots can be skimmed with a wood filler, but it's usually not for most finish flooring.

Comment: I'll be getting back into it tomorrow after work. I'll soon be able to ascertain the presence/efficacy of any adhesive.

To be sure I understand: If there isn't any adhesive, it sounds possible to remove the OSB intact, but if it is there and they actually did a "good job" I'm going to have a problem not breaking it up.

Would it be easier to saw out the OSB along the joists and then nail in some sisters to put the OSB back in place?